# error FS0001: The type 'int' does not match the type 'float'

Tags: f#

I have a simple temperature converter class that I am trying to work on.

```
open System

type Converter() = 
 member this.FtoC (f : float) = (5/9) * (f - 32.0)

 member this.CtoF(c : float) = (9/5) * c + 32.0

let conv = Converter()

54.0 |> conv.FtoC  |> printfn "54 F to C: %A" 

32.0 |> conv.CtoF |> printfn "32 C to F: %A"
```

I am getting the following compile errors

```
prog.fs(4,46): error FS0001: The type 'float' does not match the type 'int'

prog.fs(4,39): error FS0043: The type 'float' does not match the type 'int'
```

What am I missing? What part of the code it is inferring as int ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# does not automatically convert integers to floats, so you need:

```
type Converter() = 
  member this.FtoC (f : float) = (5.0/9.0) * (f - 32.0)
  member this.CtoF(c : float) = (9.0/5.0) * c + 32.0
```

In your original code `5/9` is of type `int` and `f-32.0` is of type `float`. Numerical operators like `*` require both arguments to be of the same type, so you get an error. In the fixed version, I used `5.0/9.0`, which is of type `float` (because it uses floating-point numerical literals), and so the compiler is happy.

Comment: Even the division of two integers is not inferred as a single or float ?

Comment: No, it is an integer division `9/5=1` while `9.0/5.0=1.8`. In fact, using an integer division and then converting the result to float would be an error, because you'd get 1 rather than 1.8!